# location.hash inside iframe not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I'm trying to display an HTML5 slideshow inside an iframe (based on [Google's html5slides](http://code.google.com/p/html5slides/)). The current slide number is set in the URL hash to be able to directly jump to it.

But it doesn't work in Firefox. The tricky part is that I populate the iframe's content using javascript, so my iframe doesn't have a src attribute. When I load my slideshow's code in the iframe, it is correctly displayed on Chrome, Opera, Safari, even IE9. But on Firefox it loads for a split second then loads my parent page inside the iframe.

I suspect that setting the hash inside the iframe doesn't work in firefox because I have no src attribute (I tested with an empty src attribute and it's the same)

So is there another way to set the url's hash of an iframe in javascript that would work with firefox?

You can see the bug in firefox if you paste this page content's in jsbin.com with real-time preview: http://html5slides.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/template/index.html
In firefox jsbin will load itself inside the preview iframe.